# fastest way to compare unsigned char* and const char*

Tags: c++, string

What is the fastest way to compare unsigned char* and const char* ?

Say, I have

```
    unsigned char* msg;  //length is more than 10000
    typedef struct {
      atomic<bool> updated;
      const char cmp[10]="test    ";
      int id=10000;
    } test;
```

I want to compare msg ( starting from 30th characters) to test.cmp upto 5 length. I am doing the following code

```
    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            if (*(msg + 30+ k) != test.cmp[k]) {
                break;
            }

    }
```

Is the correct way or do you suggest something else?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does msg have any structure? Besides 10K is not a lot to look through

Comment: You can use the `==` to compare the pointers. You can cat the `unsigned char*` to `char*` and use strcmp though to compare the (unsigned) char[].

Comment: are both buffers terminated by \0 ? you don't seem to check whether msg is shorter than 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `strncmp`, this way you can compare the first 5 characters, and by passing msg+30, the first character is the 30th

```
if (strncmp(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(msg+30), &(test.cmp), 5)==0){
    printf("match");
}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/

Using `memcmp` is a mistake, because cmp is a NULL terminated string and memcmp won't terminate the comparison on the NULL byte.

Comment: +1 for "Using memcmp is a mistake, because cmp is a NULL terminated string and memcmp won't terminate the comparison on the NULL byte.", forgot that, my bad

Comment: I am getting following error  invalid conversion from unsigned char* to const char* [-fpermissive]

Comment: @user3260595, updated with a reinterpret_cast. Maybe, a better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can give [memcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/) try. Although i don't know if it will work properly while comparing pointers which differ in sings.

You can also try to change type of msg to just char *, if it does not collide with the rest of your program and use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) or [strncmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/)